# How often can you harvest Sleeping Tree Sap?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360, pc

How often can you harvest Sleeping Tree Sap from the Sleeping Tree in the Sleeping Tree Camp?

I've previously heard that it refreshes daily, or when the site resets (7 days after last visit?), or that someone was never again able to harvest sap.  Others have said that they have harvested multiple items immediately.

Can anyone clarify this?

I have the game for the PC and Xbox-360.  Answers for other systems (should be the same) will be considered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As version 1.3+ Skyrim has a bug where harvestable flora doesn't respawn correctly. Sleeping Tree Sap should indeed respawn when the cell resets (every 2 days), but this only occurs when the two days pass in the same game session. Reloading a save file triggers the bug; the flora will not respawn until the next cell reset after a file is loaded.

Players have different average play lengths, and that explains the differing information you have heard from others.

On the PC version, there is a mod that can fix this behavior via a workaround: http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/31268/ On the Xbox 360 version, you must simply wait out the time and harvest the material before suspending play.